# Is an API available to query Deep links for Windows Phone 7 apps in the marketplace?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have seen couple of Web sites that list Windows Phone 7 apps from the marketplace with deep links.

Is an API available for the Windows Phone 7 Marketplace that allows me to query and maybe create a better Marketplace?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To query marketplace, you can use service which Zune desktop software uses (you can use fiddler to see what service it calls to get data about apps).

For example, if you want to search for XYZ in the marketplace for apps, following URL will return the XML data back which you can parse and display the data.

http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-US/apps?q=XYZ&clientType=WinMobile%207.0&store=zest

Comment: Thanks Jigar. Was about to do something similar but was hoping to find a better way. However this technique works.

Comment: appears that this type of linking is now broken. does anyone know of the new way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API (ATM) but you could always scrape the feeds for the marketplace like a number of websites do.

You couldn't create your own marketplace though. From the marketplace requirements:

> Your application may not consist of, distribute, link to, or incent users to download, or 
>   otherwise promote alternate marketplaces for applications and/or games.

Comment: My intention is not recreate a marketplace but say a better organized website for Windows Phone 7 apps.