# how to get the data of appointed category in windows phone Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have  learnt the page that [Is an API available to query Deep links for Windows Phone 7 apps in the marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651732/is-an-api-available-to-query-deep-links-for-windows-phone-7-apps-in-the-marketpl) but, It can only get the info of an appointed app, or the first 100 Infomation of all the apps .

How can I get the data of all app?

And how can I get the apps in games or business only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get details from the marketplace you'll have to query the same RSS feeds that the Zune client uses.

To get the details of all apps you'll need to iterate all the categories and step through each page by using the `afterMarker` parameter.
e.g.

http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-US/appCategories/windowsphone.entertainment/apps?afterMarker=KwEAAAE%3d&orderBy=downloadRank&store=Zest&clientType=WinMobile+7.1